# Count nodes having different values against same key as different variable names in a single iteration

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am working on something with neo4j.
My database has a label called 'Request' which has one particular property, the key is 'status' and the value can be 'APPROVED', 'PENDING' or 'REJECTED'.
Now I want to count all the request nodes as totalNodes, nodes that have request.status = "APPROVED" as approvedRequests, nodes which have request.status = "PENDING" as pendingRequests, and same with request.status = "REJECTED". I had done one implementation earlier like this

```
match
    (shop:Shop)
    -[:HAS_request]->
    (request:Request)

with count(distinct request) as totalrequests,
sum(case when request.status = "APPROVED" then 1 else 0 end) as appovedrequests,
sum(case when request.status = "PENDING" then 1 else 0 end) as pendingRequests,
sum(case when request.status = "REJECTED" then 1 else 0 end) as rejectedRequests

return totalrequests, approvedRequests, pendingRequests, rejectedRequests
```

but I think it will use multiple passes for all the request nodes. I want to declare these 3 variables (approvedReq, pendingReq, rejectedReq) and start iterating the request label nodes and when request.status = 'approved' , approvedReq should increase by 1, request.status = 'pending', pendingReq should increase by 1, and the same goes for 'rejected' case. This way I don't have to iterate all the nodes 3 times. Is there any way I can do it in a single pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, using a combination of `APOC` functions and `reduce`:

```
MATCH (shop:Shop)-[:HAS_request]->(request:Request)
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT r) AS requests
WITH size(requests) AS totalRequests, 
reduce(accumulator = {approvedRequests: 0, rejectedRequests: 0, pendingRequests: 0}, 
req IN requests | CASE WHEN req.status = 'APPROVED' THEN apoc.map.setEntry(accumulator, 'approvedRequests', accumulator.approvedRequests + 1)
WHEN req.status = 'PENDING' THEN apoc.map.setEntry(accumulator, 'pendingRequests', accumulator.pendingRequests + 1)
WHEN req.status = 'REJECTED' THEN apoc.map.setEntry(accumulator, 'rejectedRequests', accumulator.rejectedRequests + 1) ELSE accumulator END) AS results
RETURN totalRequests, results.approvedRequests AS approvedRequests, results.pendingRequests AS pendingRequests, results.rejectedRequests AS rejectedRequests
```

Comment: didnt know about this, definitely will try this next time  
thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to count all values in status, a simple count will do. It will be faster than iterating each nodes because it is using UNWIND and COUNT. However, the result is three rows instead of one so you need to handle it in your code later on.

```
MATCH (shop:Shop)-[:HAS_request]->(request:Request)
WITH collect(distinct request) as requests 
WITH requests, size(requests) as totalRequests
UNWIND requests as request
WITH request.status as status, count(*) as cnt, totalRequests
RETURN status, cnt, totalRequests
```

Sample:

| status | cnt | totalRequests |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "APPROVED" | 80 | 100 |
| "PENDING" | 15 | 100 |
| "REJECTED" | 5 | 100 |

Answer (score 1):

Building on jose_bacoy's answer and your wish to have CASE statements adding up request statuses:

```
MATCH (shop:Shop)-[:HAS_request]->(request:Request)
WITH collect(distinct request) as requests 
WITH requests, size(requests) as totalRequests
UNWIND requests as request
sum(case when request.status = "APPROVED" then 1 else 0 end) as appovedrequests,
sum(case when request.status = "PENDING" then 1 else 0 end) as pendingRequests,
sum(case when request.status = "REJECTED" then 1 else 0 end) as rejectedRequests
RETURN totalRequests, approvedRequests, pendingRequests, rejectedRequests
```

If you wanted to see totalRequests, approvedRequests, etc. by shop, you could still do this with only one graph pass but it would be a little more complicated. Two passes would be simpler.